# Porting iPhone app to iPad fails to sign?

Tags: ipad, porting, code-signing, universal-code

I am able to create a new application profile targeted for my iPad, however, when I convert from iPhone to "Universal" device, I am getting an error in signing.

```
[BEROR]Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'rfc1034identifier' could not be found
```

Also note: I am able to run it in the simulator (which does not require signing).

It is a very old application ~OS version 2.x or 3.1 that had SDK problems which required more manual process to get the signing code into the build settings, so I would not be surprised if there is some residual foo in the build settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up starting over and created all the device certificates and provisioning profiles.  At least the new XCode knows how to put the values in plist and install the provisioning profile on the device correctly. After I got a good project configured/setup, I did find the problem in the bundle-name setting that was somehow hooked to an expired provisioning profile.

Also, I may have missed the new shorter expiry time.  Either way, I am going to mark this one as user error ... but still claim that the build error messages could do a better job of jumping to the location of the error.